# Automatically Monitor MySQL servers for crashed tables

Tags: mysql, crash, monitor

Is there some ready off the shelf solution that would periodically connect to MySQL server, check for crashed tables and automatically initiate repair and/or send administrator an email?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has come up with a MySQL Enterprise Monitor web applciation tool that helps you to monitor the MySQL Servers. It can also be used to send an alert the administrators of errors.

Comment: Looks interesting, but it's a bit of an overkill for my task it terms of features and price

Comment: Hmm yes..I tried the evaluation version. It's pretty good to monitor the queries etc. I'm not sure whether there are any open source tools that are available for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to writing a simple Scheduled task that runs myisamchk periodically

Answer (score 0):

It is not ready off the shelf, but very easy solution - every table crash is written to MySQL error log (usually .err in data directory. You can create very simple script that is awaken every X minutes and checks this log file (using tail -XXX command for example) for entries with 'marked as crashed'. Then it can alert in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Is it crash a lot? if it is crashing a lot , I think you have to find the reason for why it is crashing. May be there is a hardware problem or another problems.

Comment: voted down b/c this should be in the comments section.